# DateAdd proper date variable recognition

Tags: vba, excel

So I've gone over this code for the best part of 4 hours fiddling with it, rewriting from scratch. The only thing I got out of this was the reduction in the code from about 15 lines to the now 9.

Anyways, the problem with the code is that it is not properly recognizing the arrDateTime date with the intArrayIndex-1. Instead of the normal date say "June 7, 2013", which I can retrieve inside the k=0 if statement, it comes back with "December 30, 1899" which I read occurs when the date statement is incorrect.

Also, I've tried using specific numbers just to test them out and it has no problem in the j=0 portion, however, for some reason the j=1 statement didn't work. I've also tried simplyfying the code by having the 1-j instead of the 1 in the DateAdd variable, however it doesn't want to add no days.

```
'grabs date and time
If (k = 0) Then
    intDay = Cells(intRowNum + 2, 2).Value
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateValue(strMonth & " " & intDay & ", " & intYear) + (Cells(intRowNum + intMaxRows + 3, 1).Value)
ElseIf j = 0 Then
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateAdd("d", 1, arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1))
ElseIf j = 1 Then
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1)
End If
```

I'm getting desperate here, any help whatsoever in figuring out why the date variable is incorrectly used would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

As requested I have included absolutely every piece of code relative to the problem, I didn't include everything as it's 400+ lines long.

```
Dim intRowNum As Integer
Dim intMaxRows As Integer
Dim intArrayIndex As Integer
Dim intYear As Integer
Dim intDay As Integer
Dim strMonth As String

Dim arrTitle(0 To 9) As String
Dim arrDescription(0 To 9) As String
Dim arrProf(0 To 9) As String
Dim arrDateTime(9) As Date

For j = 0 To 1
     For k = 0 To 4
        intArrayIndex = k * 2 + j

        'grabs date and time
        If (k = 0) Then
            intDay = Cells(intRowNum + 2, 2).Value
            arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateValue(strMonth & " " & intDay & ", " & intYear) + (Cells(intRowNum + intMaxRows + 3, 1).Value) 
        ElseIf j = 0 Then
            arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateAdd("d", 1, arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1))
        ElseIf j = 1 Then
            arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1)
        End If

    Next
Next

For j = 0 To 9

    ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + j, 1).Value = j + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + j, 5).Value = TimeValue(arrDateTime(j))
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + j, 6).Value = MonthName(month(arrDateTime(j)))
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + j, 7).Value = Day(arrDateTime(j))
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + j, 8).Value = Year(arrDateTime(j))

Next
```

Comment: The comma is there, so I'm not quite sure what you're getting at.

Comment: what value is inside this `arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1)` when is called? you could check it with any debugging tools...

Comment: arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1) = 12:00:00 AM 

And I've tried DateSerial, but it isn't the proper format for the date variable.

Comment: so, you have correct result, if you add 1 day to 12:00 AM you get `1899-12-31`... your problem is somewhere in the way you create your array of dates.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, in this case arrDateTime(0) is set to a specific date ("February 4, 2013") as thats what the variables happen to be. When intArrayIndex = 0, arrDateTime(0) = 04/02/2013 8:00:00 AM, however when intArrayIndex = 1, arrDateTime(intArrayIndex-1) = 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: which way you defined your `Array` variable? is it dynamic array like `Dim arrDateTime()` or something like `dim arrDateTime(50)`? If the first one- which way you set array dimension?

Comment: Its a static array : Dim arrDateTime(0 To 9) As Date

Comment: so, to make any additional suggestion you need to add more of (complete?) your code...

Comment: I've added all code that could possibly be affecting it.

Comment: your complete code is different to that presented in base question? can't you see the difference which making your problem?-             `arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateAdd("d", 1, arrDateTime(1))` refers all the time to first element of the array...

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, when I mentioned earlier that I tested arrDateTime(0) I forgot to change it back before copying the code to here.

Comment: please correct your code in question that I'm lost now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iteration goes as follows:

```
Turn   j    k    intArrayIndex    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex)
   1   0    0                0    is created your date on first array position
   2   0    1                2    arrDateTime(2 -1) does not exist, it is empty/zero!!
```

therefore trying to add 1 day to zero result with what you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for baring with my stupidity, whats funny is that early on I had actually had it as -2 and -1 to account for that, but other things weren't working. Thanks again!